# Mouse Leave event in Firemonkey 10.3

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a form with a control (myControl) and a child control (myChildControl).

I want to manage the mouse exit on myControl so that I can take some actions.

The problem is that the On Mouse Leave event is fired even though the mouse is still physically inside myControls but getting over myChildControl, while in this case I wouldn't need the event to be fired.

I cannot set the HitTest property in the child control as I need to take some actions on mouse events on it too.

Conceptually the Mouse Leave event fires properly, but what's the cleanest way to manage this case?

Comment: BTW, I removed the XE from your title. The XE branding was dropped with version 10.

Comment: Depending of what your Event does you might get away by firing `OnMouseEnter` of your child control to maintain desired state when the mouse is over your child control.

Comment: @SilverWarior tried that already resulting in blinking of controls that I'm hiding/showing on those events.

Answer (score 0):

Set `HitTest = False` for the child control. Then in the `OnMouseDown` of the parent control, use `PtInRect()` to check whether the mouse down event occured over the child.

If needed you can do the same for other mouse events too.

---

**Edit** after comment regarding several child controls.

I don't really agree with you about messyness. Following example for any number of child controls that might need to respond to mouse down events, on the parent control (TPanel in this example). Adding the last two lines for eventual other events is not a big deal, IMO.

```
procedure TForm20.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  ctrl: TControl;
begin
  for ctrl in (Sender as TControl).Controls do
    if PtInRect(ctrl.ParentedRect, PointF(X, Y)) then
      if assigned(ctrl.OnMouseDown) then
        ctrl.OnMouseDown(ctrl, Button, Shift, x-ctrl.Position.X, y-ctrl.Position.Y);
end;
```

---

A completely different approach, would be to use the `OnMouseEnter` event of the control your parent control is placed on (or if placed on the form, which doesn't have a `OnMouseEnter`, use the `OnMouseMove`), to trigger the `OnExit` substitute. As this could trigger very often, you could avoid unneeded actions, by declareing a boolean for `ActionRequired`

Comment: It's not working for me as children controls are more than one with different behaviours, it would become messy. I was more thinking on capturing the mouse position and realise if it's inside the myControl rect. Couldn't find any suitable code supporting this though.